# python, двумерный массив

Tags: python

Не могу понять в чем проблема.
У меня есть двумерный массив и мне нужно удалить из него те вложенные массивы если в них есть элемент 'inf'

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, "inf"], [1, 10, 15]]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if arr[i][j] == `inf`:
            del arr[i]
```

У меня выбивает ошибку `List index out of range`.
То есть результат должен быть таким: 
`Array = [[1,2,3], [1,10,15]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего обойти список в обратном порядке

```
 for j in range(len(arr[i])-1, -1, -1):  #или reversed использовать
      if arr[i][j] == `inf`:
        del arr[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сделать так:

```
arr = list(filter(lambda x: 'inf' not in x, arr))
```

Потому, что когда Вы удаляете подсписок, длинна списка уменьшается, а кол-во проходов цикла - нет. И когда скрипт пытается взять `arr[2]`, он получает ошибку, т.к. длинна списка уже 2, т.е. последний елемент будет под индексом 1.

Comment: у меня почему-то не работает ваше решение, оно не удаляет подмаслив

Comment: Оно создает новый массив, можете написать потом `arr = list(filter...)`

Comment: ааааа, понял, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что при начале цикла в списке 3 элемента и цикл программируется на 3 прохода, но в процессе выполнения из списка удаляется 1 элемент и остаётся только 2, поэтому при попытке достать arr[i] вылетает ошибка

Comment: понял, спасибо)